# Get latitude and Longitude for column in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, gis, latitude-longitude, geopy

I have a column for which I want to get Longitude and latitude.
I did research on net and folks discussed about using geopy and Nominatim.
I also tried this code:

```
def lat(x):
try:
    gn = geocoders.GeoNames(username='yadavk')
    lat=gn.geocode(x)[1]
    return(lat)
except TypeError:
    return(0)

latitude['lat']=latitude.place.apply(lat)
```

where place is the column name in my dataframe consisting of about 100k cities,state and countries. 
This code was working fine but gives me server timeout as I am requesting a lot of cities. 
Can anyone help me me get latitude and longitude of all the 100k cities without the need to buy subscription and also doesn't take very long to give the results.
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own. I took two steps to track down the lat and long:

1. Download the list of countries, cities and their lat and long from [this place](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/).
   After downloading I made a key by joining the country and cities together and did a vlookup in excel/merge in python to find relevant latitude and longitudes. Some of the latitude and longitudes were missing for which I used the 2nd step.
2. Make an account on geonames.org and use this code to find the latitude and longitude:

   ```
   def lat(x):
   try:
      gn = geocoders.GeoNames(username='demo')
      lat=gn.geocode(x)[1]
    return(lat)
   except TypeError:
    return(0)

   latitude['lat']=latitude.place.apply(lat)
   ```

   where latitude is the dataframe consisting the names of cities and countries.

Combining these two methods, I was able to get all the latitude and longitude. Hope this helps.